# Store Data in Multiple tables via single form

Tags: html, database, laravel-5.7

I want to store data in 3 tables via single registration
 form but getting error. I have tried all the way but it is not
 allowing due to primary key constraints violation

**Controller**

```
class UserController extends Controller
    {
        public function registerLawyer(Request $request){
            $firstname = $request->get('firstname');
            $lastname = $request->get('lastname');
            $country = $request->get('country');
            $role = $request->get('role');
            $dob = $request->get('dob');
            $email = $request->get('email');
            $pass = $request->get('password');
            $aop = $request->get('pracitces');
            $licensenum = $request->get('licenseNumber');
            $license = $request->get('license');
                $data = new User();
                $data->firstname = $firstname,
                $data->lastname = $lastname,
                $data->country = $country,
                $data->role = $role,
                $data->dob = $dob,
                $data->email = $email,
                $data->password = $pass,
                $data->save();

            DB::table('lawyer')->insert([
                'practices' => $aop
            ]);
            DB::table('license')->insert([
                'licenseno' => $licensenum,
                'institution' => $license
            ]);
            return view('registerlawyer');
        }
    }
```

**registerlawyer.blade.php**

```
<form method="post">
    <h1>Signup-Legal Professional</h1>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            Enter Firstname :<input type="text" name="firstname" required><br>
            Enter Lastname  :<input type="text" name="lastname" required><br>
            Country <select name="country" required="required" class="form-control">
                        <option value="select" selected="selected">Select Country</option>
                        <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
                        <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
                        <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
                        <option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
                        <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
                        <option value="Chad">Chad</option>
                        <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
                    </select><br>
            Enter Company :<input type="text" name="company" required><br>
            Enter role :<input type="text" name="role" required><br>
            Enter DOB :<input type="date" name="dob"><br>
            Enter emailaddress :<input type="text" name="email" required><br>
            Enter password :<input type="password" name="password" required><br>
            Select Area Of practices <select name="pracitces">
                <option>Individuals</option>
                <option>Aerospace</option>
                <option>Agriculture</option>
                <option>Blockchain</option>
                <option>Construction</option>
                <option>Education</option>
                <option>Electronics</option>
            </select><br>
            Enter License Number :<input type="number" name="licenseNumber" required><br>
            Enter License Institution<input type="text" name="license" required><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

The error I am getting is

> ```
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'u_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `lawyer` (`practices`) values
> ```
>
> (Construction))

How would I get the u_id when user is not even registered?

Comment: In lawyer table, u_id is foreign key?

Comment: Yes and lawyer_id is a foreign key in license table

Answer (score 2):

```
$user_data = DB::table('users')->insertGetId([
                'firstname' => $firstname,
                'lastname' => $lastname,
                'country' => $country,
                'role' => $role,
                'dob' => $dob,
                'email' => $email,
                'password' => $pass,
            ]);

$lawyer_data = DB::table('lawyer')->insertGetId([
                'u_id' => $user_data,
                'practices' => $aop,
            ]);
$license_data = DB::table('license')->insertGetId([
                'lawyer_id' => $lawyer_data,
                'licenseno' => $licensenum,
                'institution' => $license,
            ]);
```

Comment: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object this error occurred.

Comment: In lawyer_data-> user_data=>id and same on license_data

Comment: it wont work @Bhoomipatel cause it will just show True cause data only stores in Database

Comment: @Bhoomipatel  here i am getting error now is says ,SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1216 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (SQL: insert into `license` (`lawyer_id`, `licenseno`, `institution`) values (5, 12312321, adsadasdsad))

Comment: Can you `echo $lawyer_data->id;` ? and your field name is `lawyer_id`?

Comment: Yes ,i have tried that too but not working..tried this also, 'lawyer_id' => $lawyer_data->u_id_id,

Comment: Make sure you have `lawyer_id` in the **fillable** property of your `Lawyer` model.

Comment: currently i am not using Model ,everything is written in controller only at the end of project we will follow mvc pattern,do you have any other idea?

Comment: yes, i have another solution. Please try updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184071/discussion-between-prathamesh-and-bhoomi-patel). as stackoverflow is asking to discuss in chat room, i have send u the updated code

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code :

```
$user_data = DB::table('users')->insert([
           'firstname' => $firstname,
           'lastname' => $lastname,
           'country' => $country,
           'role' => $role,
           'dob' => $dob,
           'email' => $email,
           'password' => $pass,
       ]);
$user = DB::table('users')->where(['firstname'=>$firstname])->first();
$lawyer_data = DB::table('lawyer')->insert([
           'u_id' => $user->id,
           'practices' => $aop
       ]);
$law = DB::table('lawyer')->where(['u_id'=>$user->id])->first(['id']);
$license_data = DB::table('license')->insert([
           'lawyer_id' => $law->u_id,
               'licenseno' => $licensenum,
               'institution' => $license
           ]);
return redirect('welcome');
```